# Can't handle routes using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just starting out and I've got a barebones app here with a routes file ./routes/index.js.

When I browse to http://localhost:3000/index for example index.js is hit but none of the routes match and the program just goes straight through to "return router;". If I browse to http://localhost:3000/ I get the same again.

All the browser does is think about it for a bit and then give me a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blah');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash());

app.use(require('./routes/index'));

module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function authorize(req, res, next) {
    if (true) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
    }
}

module.exports = function(){

    router.get('/index', function(req, res) {
        res.send('index');
    });

    router.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res) {
        res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
    });

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('root');
    });

    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

app.js is missing a line to actually start the server.  You need to add this:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I'm using Webstorm so I believe this is wired in somehow (when I start it my console shows "Server listening on port 3000"). I can see the requests being received by the server. When debugging the program just falls straight through to return router (bypassing the router.gets)

Comment: The `router.get()` operations are just registering route handlers.  It should just execute them all and then return when your server starts as there's nothing to do upon startup other than just register the routes that you want handlers for.  As for webStorm, I've commented on the code you've shown.  I guess you're saying that there is more code.  Maybe that other code is also part of your problem.  We have no idea without seeing everything that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end... I changed

```
module.exports = function(){

    router.get('/index', function(req, res) {
        res.send('index');
    });

    router.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res) {
        res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
    });

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('root');
    });

    return router;
}
```

to

```
router.get('/index', function(req, res) {
    res.send('index');
});

router.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('root');
});

module.exports = router;
```